# Allocation of SGA size in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, memory-management

What should we keep SGA size with respect to total RAM available in system. I found in SQL server we should allocate 4GB or 10% of available RAM (which one is higher) .

Comment: What's the use of limiting that to 10% of the RAM? A dedicated DB Oracle server should be configured to use as much RAM as possible  - typically 80% of the RAM to leave some room for the OS. If you have a server with 256GB RAM why only use 25GB of that?

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon how much memory you are going to assign for different compoenents of SGA such as buffer cache, shared pool or are you going to use dedicated server mode or shared server mode.

And you should also consider whether there are other application going to be run on the server.

[Asktom: SGA Size](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:30011178429375)